# How to find the shortest path cost with under special conditions?

Tags: graph, path, shortest

Given a weighted directed graph G = (V, E) , a source vertex s , a destination vertex t and a subset v’,  how to finds the shortest non-loop path from s to vertex t in the graph? The vertexs in the subset must be included in the path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a variant of [Traveling Salesman Problem (TSP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem).

You can transform your problem to an exact instance of TSP, by running all-to-all shortest path in the graph ([Floyd Warshall Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm)), and then create a new graph:

```
G'={V' U {s,t}, E'}
V' - the "must go through" subset
E' = { (s,v), (v,t), (u,v) | u,v in V'}  (In words: all edges between two nodes in the new graphs)
```

Now, finding the miminal path that goes through all nodes (TSP) in `G'`, is also the minimal path that meets the criteria (after expending each path between two pairs back).

Unfortunately, TSP is [NP-Complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-completeness) problem (there is no known polynomial time algorithm to solve it, and most believe one doesn't even exist), and unless your set of "must go through nodes" `V'` is relatively small (and you can afford exponential time running time of the algorithm), you will need to settle on a "good enough" algorithm, which might not be optimal.

---

Sidenote regarding "no loops" - note it might be infeasible, for example:

```
      ---------
     |         |
     v         |
s -> a -> b -> c
     |
     |
     t
```

In this example, the only path to meet the criteria is `s->a->b->c->t`

Comment: Thanks for your answer.I'm interested in this method. But I have some doubt. 

1.When I look for the **all-to-all shortest path** ,how to guarantee each path is different from others(every vertex pass is through only once).

2.TSP problem is to find a loop path which include all demand vertex,as to this problem ,what is need to change the typical algorithms?

Comment: @bigboxxx You cannot guarantee there is no loop, because there are cases like the one I mentioned above - that there is no path without a cycle.

Comment: The massion is to find the path with min weights,meanwhile each demand vertex must be visited only once .

Comment: Now,I use Dijkstra to find the nearst demand vertex,then find the one nearst from it ....  But the  result is poor. Could you give me some advise?